# how to override HABTM table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am having using rails 3 and have an HABTM(has_and_belongs_to_many) between 
users <-> emails
Also user have roles defined for users as subs, pubs which have a Model that references to itself for mapping.

I want to send some emails to trash/spam/etc for one single user.
How can I achieve, as if I delete one email it'll be removed for every user having HABTM.
I just want to show that email as trashed/spam etc.
I have a wild thought of overriding the HABTM table by setting spam/trash flags/columns in the table, so that when a user marks spam/trash to an email. He'll be able to work 
Is there any way/convention to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon you can get away with setting up your associations as shown below. Note the `dependent: :destroy`. When you delete your user ActiveRecord will cause the call `dependent: :destroy` on the model and delete the associated model with it.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :emails, through: :user_emails
  has_many :emails, dependent: destroy 
end 

class UserEmail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user 
  belongs_to :email 
end 


class Email < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :users, :through: :user_emails 
  has_many :user_emails, :dependent: :destroy 
end
```

You can have a look under [Polymorphic Associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many). Hopefully this helps

**Update Querying `has_many` Association**

```
 @UserEmail = UserEmail.find(:all,
    :joins => :user, :email,
    :conditions => ["email.email_trashed = ? ", true] 
    )
```

Not 100% certain that this will work but I reckon it is along them lines.

Comment: that means, I can create a model for that HABTM and use that ..??

Comment: @NishutoshSharma yeah you should be able to. When designing your application you should consider that it is not very good to have many-to-many relationships. Which is why we can resolve this form of cardinality by creating a resolving table. In which case this is `UserEmail`

Comment: I have made a slight change please check and confirm that purpose will be served.. so that I can mark this answer right

Comment: I have seen your edit, it sounds pretty reasonable as in if you set the fields, `spam` and `trash` to boolean fields, so that determine whether the fields have been marked will deter what happens to the email.

Comment: if I take an column, :trashed in :emails_users table then how will I find emails that are trashed => true.. I am finding it difficult to search through the columns of EmailsUser model.
Do we have any standard way of querying this has_many through table ??

Comment: @NishutoshSharma see my update hopefully it will shed some light